# Is Sheafification Functor Exact?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, limits-and-colimits, fibered-products

I know that sheafification functor from the category of abelian presheaves on $C$ to the category of abelian sheaves on $C$. Here, $C$ is a category with Grothendieck pretopology.

My question is:

How about the sheafification functor from the category of presheaves of "sets" on $C$ to the category of sheaves of "sets" on $C$?

Is this an exact functor? (i.e. preserving finite limits and finite colimits?)

If so, how can one prove it?

In fact, I want to know whether sheafification functor preserves cartesian products or not.

Please give me any advice.

Comment: the answer is yes!
for a reference you can use theorem 17.4.9 of kashiwara-schapira cats and sheaves.

Answer (score 12):

Martin has probably answered everything Hiro meant to ask, but, since "whether sheafification functor preserves cartesian products or not" didn't explicitly say *finite* products, let me add that sheafification will not in general preserve infinite products.  Intuitively, the reason is that a section of a product of sheafifications is a family of locally defined sections of the original presheaves, and there might not be a single covering over which all those local sections are simultaneously available.

Answer (score 9):

Preservation of colimits is trivial from the adjunction, preservation of finite limits comes down - using the usual construction - to the fact that finite limits commute with filtered colimits. The latter holds in every algebraic category, in particular in (Set).

Comment: what's an algebraic category?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29 or more general http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category